# Unnecessary files from R packages

Tags: r, r-package

Is there a pattern or rule for unnecessary files from R packages?

I am running R on a serverless container environment (AWS Lambda) and I'm needing to shave megabytes off, I have noticed some packages have folders called, doc, help, html, sometimes examples or tests or even translations, and these folders are often larger than the package itself, leading to several mbs per package.

I don't know much about R, but can I safely delete all these folders from these packages? Is there a pattern or list of folder names that I can safely delete?

Comment: It's difficult to give a specific answer here without knowing your use case and the packages involved. One answer could be just copying selected functions out of the package into your own code. Other packages could be avoided altogether with a rewrite of your own scripts  (often dplyr and tidyr calls can be rewritten in base R). Some packages are all-or-nothing and difficult to replicate (like ggplot2). If your code paths are fixed you might be able to delete all the help files or all the example data files. This is really too problem-specific to give a general answer.

Comment: @AllanCameron I understand that the general problem of reducing deployment size depends on the project, but what about the docs, help, html folders? I just want to know if I can delete these and if there's a patter to their naming so I can create a script to delete them